Changes made on SPFx project not visible in Teams
I have created the SPFx project and integrated that project into the Teams project. When I made the change in the SPFx project the changes were not reflected in the Teams after generating and deploying/uploading a new package in Microsoft Teams.
Can anyone help me with the same?
Thanks

You should deploy your changes to SharePoint to make it available in Teams. More information could help:

How did you create the SPFx project and integrate into Teams project? With SharePoint Yeoman generator or Teams Toolkit
What do you mean by 'generating and deploying/uploading a new package in Microsoft Teams'? Did you generate & deploy a new Teams package or deploy to overwrite the older SharePoint package after SPFx changes? What's the steps?

Also, you could always raise an GitHub issue to us if you have further problems.

For #1 - We are following the steps as per this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-spfx?tabs=vscode%2Cviscode&tutorial-step=2

For #2 - We are using these 2 commands to generate a zip package and upload this package in ti the Teams. Please check this link for more clarification - https://ibb.co/sCZ4Bzz

@thedeepponkiya, you need click 'Deploy' under 'LIFECYCLE' section after changing SPFx project logics to re-deploy the updated SharePoint package to SPO so the changes will be reflected in Teams.

Facing the Same Issues:- [Error] - Failed to Execute lifecycle deploy due to failed action: cli/runNpxCommand. ScriptExecutionError: Unable to execute script action.. Env output: {} Please check this link for more clarification https://ibb.co/PNGsNSv

From the screenshot you attached, seems the lint errors are blocking gulp command execution. Please resolve those errors first before deploy could run successfully.
